# ModuleNotFoundError while module was installed using pip

Tags: python, django, pip, virtualenv

This is a very weird situation. I've been using django and venv for a while and during my last pull of code, when trying to run `python manage.py collectstatic`, I ran into a **ModuleNotFoundError**. However, the module is installed and if I try to reinstall it, pip tells me I already have it.

The strange thing is I'm seeing importlib using my system python path ("/usr/lib/python3.6...") which  I think it should be my virtualenv path...

If I run `which python` I get the correct venv python path...

This is the error I get:

```
File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py",
   line 90, in create
       module = import_module(entry)   
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in
   import_module
       return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import   
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load   
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django-mailbox'
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably installed django using `pip install django`. This installs the module for the Python installation corresponding to the `pip` executable that is found in your path. If you have multiple Python versions installed, it could be that the `pip` command points to your Python 3.5 installation (for example), while the `python` command points to your Python 3.6 installation.

To make sure that you install the packages for the correct Python version, instead of:

```
pip install <package>
```

use:

```
python -m pip install <package>
```

or, if you want to use a specific Python version:

```
python3.6 -m pip install <package>
```

(In the latter case you should run your application using `python3.6 your_application.py`)